# PrintDialog.ShowDialog(this) immediately returns DialogResult.Cancel on Windows 7

Tags: .net, winforms, printing, windows-7, printdialog

An in house application that I'm developing is behaving strange on a Windows 7 (64 bit) PC.

If I create an instance of a PrintDialog, and call it's ShowDialog() method, the method immediately returns DialogResult.Cancel without showing the printer dialog form.

The Windows 7 PC does have printers installed (with a working default printer).

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();

printDialog.PrinterSettings.Copies = 2;
printDialog.AllowCurrentPage = false;
printDialog.AllowPrintToFile = false;
printDialog.AllowSelection = false;
printDialog.AllowSomePages = false;
DialogResult dialogResult = printDialog.ShowDialog(this);

if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
    return;
```

Any clues why this is happening?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Set `printDialog.UseEXDialog` to `true` to work around this bug.

In .Net 3.5, [MSDN mentions this potential problem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.useexdialog(v=vs.90).aspx) when documenting `UseEXDialog`:

> When this property is set to `true`, `ShowHelp` and `ShowNetwork` will be ignored as these properties were made obsolete for Windows 2000 and later versions of Windows. **Also, The `PrintDialog` class may not work on AMD64 microprocessors unless you set the `UseEXDialog` property to `true`.**

*(My emphasis.)*

The same page for [.Net 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.useexdialog%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [.Net 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.useexdialog.aspx) don't include the emphasized bit, so perhaps it's fixed in those versions.

Comment: Thanks, For anyone else interested, the MSDN article for UseExDialog has more comments about this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.useexdialog.aspx

Comment: My initial googling didn't find anything useful, however now that I know the solution, there is plenty of reading material on this issue http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=UseExDialog+cancelled

Comment: Thanks. Very intuitive of Microsoft to hide functionality after something with a name like that.